# Multiprocessing slow when other code is not commented out

Tags: python, multiprocessing, buffer

I'm trying to learn multiprocessing and have used this set of code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import math, time

def isPrime(n):
    if n<2:
        return False
    if n==2:
        return True
    max = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)))
    i = 2
    while i <= max:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i +=1
    return True
def sumPrimes(n):
    return sum([x for x in xrange(2,n) if isPrime(x)])

li = list(xrange(0, 50000, 1000))

# TEST 1
st = time.time()
results = []
for l in li:
    results.append(sumPrimes(l))
print results
print "Took %s seconds." % repr(time.time()-st), "\n"

# TEST 2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = time.time()
    pool = Pool(4)
    results = pool.map(sumPrimes, li)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()    
    print results
    print "Took %s seconds." % repr(time.time()-st)
```

If I run **both test 1 and test 2 together, I get that test 1 took 3.500 seconds and test 2 took 9.161 seconds**. The output also comes in one moment - I would expect test 2 to output 9.16 seconds after test 1.

However, **if I comment out test 1, test 2 takes 2.152 seconds**. This is good because the multiprocessing is working.

However, why do I have to comment out the first test just for it to work? Am I measuring something wrong? And why does the output come out all in one moment when I run both tests at the same time?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this running on windows? If so, TEST 1 needs to be inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` or it will be executed by all subprocesses. Its good practice to do that anyway.

Comment: Ok that seems to have fixed the measurement times. Now TEST 2 is faster as it should be. However, TEST 2 and TEST 1 still print to the console at the same exact time, when TEST 2 should be printing after TEST 1 by how many seconds it takes to run - do you know why this is? (also would you like to post as an answer)

Comment: There was a delay on my machine. Are you running this on the command line or as a child of another program? The output will be buffered if stdout is not a console. You can add `print 'console? ', sys.stdout.isatty()` after importing sys to see. If `isatty` is false, the program buffers its output and you'll get the behavior you describe.

Comment: Yep it's FALSE (I'm using Spyder and not the terminal). That clarifies things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, multiprocessing rebuilds the program state by importing modules so that it can unpickle the objects needed for processing. In particular, it imports the main module. This  means that all top-level commands will be executed. In your case, the child process re-executes TEST 1 which skews your performance numbers.

Code nested in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block are not executed because when a module is imported as opposed to run as a script, it's module name is not "**main**" (unless you named your module `__main__.py`). You can move TEST 1 under `__main__` or make it a function that is called under `__main__`.